# Does nonce same for all node?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

Suppose in blockchain network we have 5 nodes and we have new transaction done by first node of network, so now rest of 4 node will mine the transaction to commit it in blockchain network, will the nonce be same for all node mining the same transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A miner (honest) more or less,in high level, runs the following algorithm:

1. Listens the network for transactions and blocks.
2. Constructs a block that includes: a) all valid transactions b) a reference to the previous block (parent hash) c) new state.
3. Search for a proof of work based on the constructed block in step 2.
4. If she finds a block she broadcast it to the network.
5. If another miner found a block she drops her previous work and continue the mining in the most recent block.

Proof-of-Work (high level):

```
H(state || txs || nonce || parent-blockid) < T
```

where T is the target.

To find a proof of work each miner runs the following algorithm (high level / pseudocode):

```
do {
    nonce = rand();
} while (H(state || txs || nonce || parent-blockid) >= T);

return nonce;
```

So the nonce is totally random and that's what miners try to find: a nonce that satisfies a condition.

The first miner to find a block wins and all other honest miners drop their work and start mining on the new block (miners adopt the "heaviest" chain).

---

Previous answer (account nonce)

The nonce is part of the state of the account. The global state of Ethereum consists of all accounts. A change in the state of an account is a change in the global state. All nodes of the network have to agree on that state. The agreement to the new global state is being made with the use of a consensus algorithm such as Proof-of-Work (PoW). At the end all nodes will agree on the same nonce.

Comment: So how the nonce is decided? That this nonce will be same across network, mean all nodes are mining and calculating their own nonce and matching the hash(block data + nonce) with targetHash value whether it is less than or equal to targetHash value so there are chances that many nodes find such type of nonce that satisfy the condition

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake. I thought you meant the account nonce. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: In this code 
do {
    nonce = rand();
} while (H(state || txs || nonce || parent-blockid) >= T);

return nonce; 
your hash of H((state || txs || nonce || parent-blockid))) is grater  than Target Hash
but I read that is should be less than or equal to.

Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: The do-while loop should run until a valid nonce is found. So the condition in the do-loop says if the H(...) is bigger than T continiue looping. If not stop and return the valid nonce.

Comment: oh yes thank you, mean it will return the nonce which is less than or equal to target hash when it exit from loop

Comment: Exactly! If you arw satisfied with the answer please accept it as correct